Opening port 443 Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I need to open ports 22, 80 and 443.  222 and 80 are good, but 443 refuses the connection. The ufw is active. I'm not sure how to open 443.
root@server:~# sudo nc -lu 172.86.183.86 443
^C
root@server:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       140.228.139.96            
80/tcp                     ALLOW       140.228.139.96            
443/tcp                    ALLOW       140.228.139.96            
80/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.0.2               
443/tcp                    ALLOW       192.168.0.2               
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/udp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

root@server:~# nc -zv 172.86.183.86 443
nc: connect to 172.86.183.86 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
root@server:~# nc -zv 172.86.183.86 80 
Connection to 172.86.183.86 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
root@server:~# nc -zv 172.86.183.86 22 
Connection to 172.86.183.86 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
root@server:~# 


Do you have a server listening on port 443?  There isn't going to be anything listening on port 443 unless you have a server process (like a web server) running on that port.

I'm trying to set up this server. My provisioning instructions are to open ports 22, 80 and 443. re: https://gridpane.com/kb/how-to-provision-a-custom-server-a-general-guide/

See if you can a) connect to localhost:443 from the machine in question. If that works, then again connect to the same machine but from the PUBLIC address. If you can connect to port 443 to the local server then the server is working and not being stopped by the local machine. There's an external firewall that needs to be manipulated. Reply to this with answers and I can assist on next steps. I can also tell by the above output that ssl is being served over 443 so I bet the issue is external firewall by ISP.

I also just noticed UDP over 443. Get rid of all that configuration. 443 is http over ssl and is a TCP based, not UDP. Not sure if this is causing the issue but it is definitely not helping.

@RonaldJohnson HTTP/3 / QUIC uses udp/443 fyi.  And yes that is a thing.  But most sites don't use it so yes, tcp/443 is usually the only one that needs openend

If you say so. As it's a configuration I don't have direct experience in, I'll just assume you know what you're talking about.

Other than the fact that I also have some code which is HTTP3 QUIC based and have no need of such special configuration on 443. In fact on my setup it is detrimental as I have just tested it in the last 10 seconds.

Just did some rather quick orienting myself to your specific setup as well as configuration details the only other point of contention I have discovered is ssl related. Make sure your openssl subsystem is configured properly as the the first thing http/3-quic does is to make sure the communication line being used is tls encrypted properly. If not, depending on how it's setup it will either silently fail or leave a message in the apache2 logs.
